# Circular Inheritance for validation

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, .net-4.0

I want to build an object model that automatically wires in validation when I attempt to save an object.  I am using DataAnnotations for my validation, and it all works well, but I think my inheritance is whacked.  I am looking here for some guidance on a better way to wire in my validation.

So, to build in validation I have this interface

```
public interface IValidatable
{
    bool IsValid { get; }
    ValidationResponse ValidationResults { get; }
    void Validate();
}
```

Then, I have a base class that all my objects inherit from.  I did a class because I wanted to wire in the validation calls automatically.  The issue is that the validation has to know the type of the class is it validating.  So I use Generics like so.

```
public class CoreObjectBase<T> : IValidatable where T : CoreObjectBase<T>  
{
    #region IValidatable Members

    public virtual bool IsValid
    {
        get
        {
            // First, check rules that always apply to this type
            var result = new Validator<T>().Validate((T)this);

            // return false if any violations occurred
            return !result.HasViolations;
        }
    }

    public virtual ValidationResponse ValidationResults
    {
        get
        {
            var result = new Validator<T>().Validate((T)this);
            return result;
        }
    }

    public virtual void Validate()
    {
        // First, check rules that always apply to this type
        var result = new Validator<T>().Validate((T)this);

        // throw error if any violations were detected
        if (result.HasViolations)
            throw new RulesException(result.Errors);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

So, I have this circular inheritance statement.  My classes look like this then:

```
public class MyClass : CoreObjectBase<MyClass>
{

}
```

But the problem occurs when I have a more complicated model.  Because I can only inherit from one class, when I have a situation where inheritance makes sense I believe the child classes won't have validation on their properties.

```
public class Parent : CoreObjectBase<Parent>
{
    //properties validated
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    //properties not validated?
}
```

I haven't really tested the validation in these cases yet, but I am pretty sure that anything in child with a data annotation on it will not be automatically validated when I call Child.Validate(); due to the way the inheritance is configured.  Is there a better way to do this?

**EDIT:**

For further clarification, here is my validation.  This is using `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`.

```
public sealed class Validator<T> where T : CoreObjectBase<T>
{
    public ValidationResponse Validate(T entity)
    {
        var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
        var context = new ValidationContext(entity, null, null);
        var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(entity, context, validationResults);

        return new ValidationResponse(validationResults.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: You could run into problems if you had `Foo : CoreObjectBase<Foo>` and then someone else legally defined `Bar : CoreObjectBase<Foo>`. When you cast `this` to `T`, `this` is `Bar` but `T` is `Foo`, and these types are not inherently compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you are using inheritance for this - you are already delegating the validation to an external class (`Validator<T>`) so you should be able to completely separate the validation process from the target object.

Comment: Because I want any class in my model to have validation automatically wired in without having to set it up for each class.  By using inheritance, since the base class has the validation defined, any children of the base class have validation built in.  And the reason I am doing it this way as that the external validation requires that it knows the type of the object being validated.

Comment: You led me down a road I am going to attempt, which is to remove the Generics from the validation (and thus remove them from the `CoreObjectBase`).